# unable to add values to multichoice dialog box in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have small problem in android for Multichoice dialog box.

I have done with this below code for showing a multichoice dialog box and calling that on button click event.
I have set Title, Message, Button and also add Items to the dialog box.

I can see the title, Message and Button that I have set, but I am unable to see the items which I am adding. for that I have googled and almost tried all the code which I found in searching. All approaches not helped me.

Here is my code...

```
final String[] Values={"Red","Green","Blue"}; 
final boolean[] selCrayons={true,false,true};
AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setTitle("Crayons List");
dialog.setMessage("Select your favouriate Crayon");
dialog.setMultiChoiceItems(Values,selCrayons,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Color is " + Values[arg1],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
dialog.setPositiveButton("SAVE",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setMessage` and `setMultiChoiceItems` will not work together. Remove `setMessage` and you will be able to see the multi-choice item list.

If there is a need to use message and multi-choice list together, you can use your own custom view for the dialog.

For how to set custom view, you can refer [AlertDialog.Builder setView (View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this before, remove `dialog.setMessage()`, unfortunately you can't have both a message and multi-choice